# Move image with mouse wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mouse, kinect

> Hello, I have been trying to work this problem out for some time now,
>   I hope that you are able to lead me in the right direction!

The goal is to have a "flashlight" effect in my wpf game, to do this I have pursued 2 main options.

1. Have a black png image that is 200% width & height of window with a hole in the center, then move the image with the mouse
2. Have a black image the size of the window, and have an opacity mask element that is a circle shape that looks through the black layer to the content below. This circle moves with the mouse.

I cannot get either of these options to work, in wpf when you have an opacity mask it appears you cannot move the element that is "punching through" the layer. And for the large image method, I cannot convert a mouse Point object to an image's position. Below are some potential methods of getting mouse position, I have not been able to move the image to "point" location.

Point to screen

```
private void MouseCordinateMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var relativePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
    var point= PointToScreen(relativePosition);
    _x.HorizontalOffset = point.X;
    _x.VerticalOffset = point.Y;
}
```

GetPosition

```
var point = e.GetPosition(this.YourControl);
```

The final game will be using kinect for controls, so if there is a way to do this with kinect libraries or natively that is also an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a Path element with a `CombinedGeometry` consisting of a very large `RectangleGeometry` and an excluded (and therefore transparent) `EllipseGeometry`, which is moved by changing its `Center` property on mouse input:

```xml
<Grid MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello, World" FontSize="40"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Path Fill="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,10000,10000"/>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="circle" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

The MouseMove handler:

```
private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    circle.Center = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I owe you big time. We had 3 guys working on this and none of us succeeded. Really simple and easy to understand, movement/updating is a little choppy but I will see if I can improve that part of it. thank you so much! edit:: Nevermind, the choppiness is when there is nothing beneath the transparent level. It goes smooth with objects beneath it!